# AI - Heuristic function requirements

Tags: algorithm, function, search, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I have a question about Huristic function in Artificial Intelligence (AI).
I know that we should look for monotonic and admissible heuristic function.

I have two questions:

1. Why is it required that the function will be admissible?
2. What are the advantages of monotonic heuristic functions?

Thank you!

Comment: You're talking about A* specifically, right?

Comment: @delnan - Yes. I'm talking about A*

Comment: @zeevblu Have you read the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic? There's also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An **admissible** heuristic is one that provides a lower bound estimate to the goal state.

A **monotonic** (also known as consistent) heuristic will allow you to implement an optimal A* search efficiently. It guarantees optimality if you visit each state only once.

Answer (score 3):

For the admissibility - it gives you a lower bound for the optimal solution.